# How to stop the application running using the "Gradle application plugin"?

Tags: java, gradle, git-bash

I have a multi-module java application. I have to run each module separately. I use gradle application plugin for runnig module.

The application runs on Windows 10, Intellij Idea 2019.2.4, Java 11, gradle 5.6.4

It's execution stuck's on 90%, but it works. However, I can't adequetly stop that application. With the key combination "Ctrl + C" on the terminal of the idea, the idea gives me the message "Stop termitating?(Y/n)". If I stop it like that the idea just kill the process and the application will stop with failure.
When I run the module on git-bash, I can't stop the application, even by pressing "Ctrl + C".

How to adequately stop the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

- type `Ctrl Z`
- execute `kill -9 %`
- type `Ctrl C`